# Visual studio 2008 express crashes when writing method call

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, google-api

I'm using to Google Calendar API v3 and following the samples to create the windows form application I need. I have an issue in the getAuthorization method provided in the sample.

Basically whenever I write down aut.RefreshToken(... Visual studio crashes

Here's my getAuthorization method:

```
Private Shared Function GetAuthorization(ByVal arg As NativeApplicationClient) As IAuthorizationState
    Dim scopes() As String = { _
            CalendarService.Scopes.Calendar.GetStringValue, _
            CalendarService.Scopes.CalendarReadonly.GetStringValue _
        }
    ' Get the auth URL:
    Dim state As IAuthorizationState = New AuthorizationState(scopes)
    state.Callback = New Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl)
    Dim refreshToken As String = GetRefreshToken()
    If refreshToken <> "" Then
        state.RefreshToken = refreshToken

        'If arg.RefreshToken(state) Then
        '    SaveRefreshToken(refreshToken)
        '    Return state
        'End If
    End If

    Dim authUri As Uri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state)

    ' Request authorization from the user (by opening a browser window):
    Process.Start(authUri.ToString())

    Dim authCode As String = ""
    While authCode = ""
        authCode = InputBox("Paste the code provided by Google here:", "Verification code")
    End While

    ' Retrieve the access token by using the authorization code:
    Dim result = arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state)
    SaveRefreshToken(refreshToken)
    Return result
End Function
```

As it can be seen, the arg.RefreshToken block has been commented. If I try to uncomment it or writing it again, VS crashes.

I have to point out that I've tried this code on VS Pro 2010 and worked without any problems

Comment: Microsoft (R) Visual Basic Compiler is what's crashing

Comment: Maybe you should send a bug report to microsoft.

Comment: Unfortunatly Microsoft connect isn't accepting bug report for VS 2012 or below :/

Comment: :-( Why don't you just update to a newer VS version?

Comment: Cannot cause of some old work applications... I'll try compiling a dll on another PC with the VS 2010 and see if it still crashes the 2008

Comment: Compiling the method in a dll on its own in VS 2010 worked as I expected, however if anyone ever encountered anything similar, I would appreciate any help as this solution is far from ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling the method in a dll on its own in VS 2010 worked as I expected, however if anyone ever encountered anything similar, I would appreciate any help as this solution is far from ideal.